# Sending text messages with perl?

Tags: perl, text, mobile-phones

Is there a way to send text messages for free or cheap with Perl? I see a lot of things on CPAN, but they all cost quite a bit. Is there anyway to send an email as a text message?

Comment: Contact me and I can get you anything you want on CPAN for half price :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some providers have email addresses that are formatted like so: 1234567890@sms.provider.com.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carriers_providing_SMS_transit

Comment: I'd say "some providers", not "most" - over here, only 1 out of 3 providers supports it, and only allows 10 e-mails per day, silently dropping the rest. The list you provide definitely doesn't list *most* operators.

Comment: Edited to say "Some" instead.

It does depend on where you live though. A lot of the major North American companies offer it and looking at that list, I don't think I know anyone who's not with one of those providers.

Comment: This works great. I will only be using US companies so it will be one of the major 4 companies I am sure.

Comment: I use this method if I want a script I write to text me if somethings happens, it works well if you know the carrier network.

Comment: That is what I am using it for

Answer (score 2):

I did a Google search for 'text message gateway', and http://cardboardfish.com looks cheap. They provide explicit Perl support.

Comment: I just checked them, something is wrong with their web site. For example, I get their error page when I click on their pricing links.

Answer (score 2):

Most if not all mobile phone providers do have email to SMS gateways set up.  The problem, of course, is that you must know which provider the person you're texting is using, and have a list of the providers' email addresses built in to your application; it's much more convenient (though non-free) to use a commercial gateway that can send to any mobile phone number.